# ADT Eclipse on Linux

Tags: linux, android, eclipse, gaming, ide

is it possible programming for Android using the ADT on Eclipse on Linux?

I would like to programming using cocos2D-X on Linux because it is much easer to setup all the environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for doing so in Linux, also when you work with some NDK's, Linux is better than windows in many ways. for ADT bundle for Linux you can refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)